# Access to the path is denied when trying to run ASP.NET Core app in docker with https

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

I'm trying to start an asp.net core app using docker, and I wanted to set https support.

This is my `compose.yaml`:

```
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      target: final        
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./webroot:/app/wwwroot/.well-known:ro
      - ./https/:/app/https/:rw
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path: /app/https
```

When the container starts I get this error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/app/https' is denied. System.IO.IOException: Permission denied

The error is shown in the container logs in docker-desktop, Windows.

The error is initiated when calling `app.Run()` in `Program.cs`, and it started after I've added `ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path: /app/https` in my `compose.yaml`.

My goal was not to make https mandatory using this code, but to configure the asp.net core app to use the certificates from the `https` folder if they are there (after letsencrypt created them)